# Passport is not serializing my user in login

Tags: passport.js

I am practicing of using `passport.js` for **authentication** but there is a problem in **login** part. I've tried to solve the problem by different way but nothing was successful, the problem is even after changing the `passport.serialize` to (user, done) the code worked but if I enter any fake password and username, it authenticate me.

How do I solve it?

```
// npm i passport passport-local passport-local-mongoose express-session

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static("public"));

const session = require("express-session"); // session first
const passport = require("passport");  //then passport
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose"); // last passport-local-mongoose
// no need to passport-local

app.use(session({  // use the session first and set it up
    secret: "this is our secrete",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize()); // then use passport to initialize
app.use(passport.session()); // then use passport to deal with session

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/authentication", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true); // to prevent the deprecation message
const authSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
})

authSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose); //plug passportLocalMongoose in the schema

const Auth = new mongoose.model("Auth", authSchema);

passport.use(Auth.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(Auth.serializeUser()); // put a message in a cookie
passport.deserializeUser(Auth.deserializeUser()); // destroy the cookie and reveal the message

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})
app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/register.html");
})
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html");
})
app.get("/success", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
})
app.get("/secret", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/secret.html")
    } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html")
    }
})

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    var regEmail = req.body.email;
    var regPassword1 = req.body.password1;
    var regPassword2 = req.body.password2;
    if (regPassword1 === regPassword2) {
        Auth.register({ username: regEmail }, regPassword1, (err, user) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            passport.authenticate('local')
            res.redirect("/success")
        })
    }
})

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const user = new Auth({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    req.login(user, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        passport.authenticate("local")
        res.redirect("/secret")
        })
    })

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening to ${port}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `/login` route is creating a new user by calling `new Auth()` and logging in with it regardless of if the password does not match the one being stored.

You should be able to use the `passport.authenticate` method on your route to verify that the user is registered in your Mongo database. This method also automatically calls `req.login`.

```js
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local",{
    successRedirect: "/secret",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}));
```

Here is a fully example that uses `passport-local-mongoose` for reference: https://gist.github.com/yukeehan/23fbbe53f1ca94be440161c1562b489a